# Find the permutations of an array using recursion

Tags: python

I came up with the following function:

```
def permutations(elements, arr, index):
    if len(elements) == index:
        print arr
    for i in xrange(index, len(elements)):
        arr[index] = elements[i]
        permutations(elements, arr, index+1)

permutations([1,2,3], [0,0,0], 0)
```

However, it's printing:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 3]
[3, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 3]
```

what's wrong with my recursion?

Comment: Try to take a look here: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: Note that this can be done with `itertools` if you just need a working solution: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found this as a Java String recursive permutation algorithm that I translated to Python. I think it's the best solution:

```
def permutation(aux, ls):
    if len(ls) == 0: 
        print(aux)
    else:
        for i in range(len(ls)):
            permutation(aux + [ls[i]], ls[0:i] + ls[i+1:len(ls)])

permutation([], [1, 2, 3])
```

This is the output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Up-vote. Pretty neat solution :) Also, mine's are a little faster ( ls[0:i] + ls[i+1:len(ls)] is O(n) ) even second do not maintain permutation order

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is that on `i-th` position only possible values are from `(i, n - 1)` where is n length of list. Thats why on last index in list you have all 3's. So the solution would be to iterate on all "levels" (`i-th` permutation call) from `(0, n - 1)`. But because you will iterate from `(0, n - 1)` on all "levels" you must introduce dictionary(used as hashset) where you will keep if some value (`j-th` element) is already chosen on previous calls. Easiest solution would be something like:

```
def perm(elements):
    def inner(arr, index, visited):
        if len(elements) == index:
            print arr
        for i in xrange(0, len(elements)):
            if (i not in visited):
                visited[i] = 1; # mark so same index can not be used later
                arr[index] = elements[i]
                inner(arr, index + 1, visited);
                del visited[i] # free index
    inner([0] * len(elements), 0, {});         

perm([1,2,3])
```

As @Hooked already mentioned it would be best if you can use [permutations function from itertools module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations). Note that on Python 3, you can put arr and visited outside of function parameters with `nonlocal`. Also, here you are one more solution, without dictionary, but with additional list which will hold all possible values for `i-th` level (position) of permutation. In this solution, however order of permutations is not preserved

```
def perm(elements):
    def inner(arr, index, possible):
        if len(elements) == index:
            print arr
        lenForLevel = len(elements) - index;
        for i in xrange(0, lenForLevel):            
            arr[index] = possible[i]
            (possible[i], possible[lenForLevel - 1]) = (possible[lenForLevel - 1], possible[i])
            inner(arr, index + 1, possible);
            (possible[i], possible[lenForLevel - 1]) = (possible[lenForLevel - 1], possible[i])
    inner([0] * len(elements), 0, list(elements))

perm([1,2,3,4])
```